# regex for mongodb url string, javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, url

I'm a bit stucked with this regex problem, I need to check if url has at start `mongodb://` and at the end of a string - port with numbers `:27017` and also if there is no slash `/` .

For example:

```
/myRegexForThis/.test('mongodb://testUrl:port') => true
/myRegexForThis/.test('mongodb://testUrl:port/') => false
/myRegexForThis/.test('mongo://testUrl') => false
/myRegexForThis/.test('mongodb://testUrl:port') => false
```

currently I have only start part: `^(mongodb:\/\/)`

Comment: There shouldn't be any slash in "testUrl" ? Also do you want to check if the URL is valid ?

Comment: url can be like ``user:pass@example.com`` but as well as simple ``localhost``

Comment: So you do want to validate if the URL is valid ? Since if you don't want to you could simply use `^mongodb:\/\/.*?:\d+$`.

Comment: yeah, i think there's no need to check, maybe only if it's not containing cyrrilic letters

Comment: Does the "testUrl" string start with http(s) ? or is it just an IP/domain ?

Comment: @HamZa url can be like user:pass@example.com but as well as simple localhost, no https

Comment: Unfortunately a mongodb resource URI can be a lot more complex than that

Comment: Here we [goooooooo](http://regex101.com/r/vB8gL0), credits goes to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2015516/) !

Comment: Example line 1 and 4, exactly the same, but different result?

Comment: For an example mongo uri parser in js: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/lib/mongodb/connection/url_parser.js